# Speedup GNU make build process - Parallelism?

Tags: gcc, build, build-process, g++, makefile

I build a huge project frequently and this takes long time (more than one hour) to finish even after configuring pre-compiled headers. Are their any guidelines or tricks to allow make work in parallel (e.g. starting gcc in background, ...etc) to allow for faster builds?

Note: Sources and binaries are too large in size to be placed in a ram file system and I don't want to change the directory structure or build philosophy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`make -jN` is a must now that most machines are multi-core. If you don't want to write `-jN` each time, you can put

```
export MAKEFLAGS=-jN
```

in your `.bashrc`.

You may also want to checkout [distcc](http://code.google.com/p/distcc/).

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
make -j<number of jobs to run in parallel>
```

Answer (score 4):

If your project is becoming too big for one machine to handle, you can use one of the distributed make replacements, such as [Electric Cloud](http://www.electric-cloud.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your build in parallel,

```
make -jN
```

does the job, but keep in mind:

1. `N` should be equal to the `maximum number of threads your machine supports`, if you enter a number greater than that, `make` automatically makes `N=maximum number of threads your machine supports`
2. `make` doesn't support parallel build using `-jN` in `MSDOS`, it just does a serial build. If you specify -`jN`, it will downgrade `N=1`.

Read more here, from the `make` source: http://cmdlinelinux.blogspot.com/2014/04/parallel-build-using-gnu-make-j.html

Comment: MSDOS != Windows, and you're wrong about parallel make in point 2.

Comment: @rubenvb: Yes, I know that. Thanks for pointing that out, the source only mentioned about `MSDOS` and not `windows`, don't know why I wrote that, Corrected!